# How to refactor in a branch without losing my mind?

Tags: refactoring, branch

I refactor my and other people's code **all the time**.
When I work in a branch and not in Trunk, this sometimes results in some extremely painful merges, especially if I don't merge back to Trunk regularly (the code at the branch slowly shifts away from the Trunc, and when people modify Trunk I have to figure out manually how to apply this to the branch).

The solutions I know are either

1. Constantly merge to and from Trunk - reduces painful merges, but then why work in a branch at all?
2. Whenever you need to refactor something, switch to Trunk, do the refactoring there and merge to your branch - I don't find this very practical, since the actual cost of switching environments for every refactoring is huge.

What do you do?

Comment: As the the Q in part 1; so you can have source control of broken code. If you live by the "Trunk always works" mindset, the only way to check in "in process" work is a branch

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Refactoring on a large scale needs to be done at the right time in the development timeline. If you do huge amounts of refactoring near release you'll end up hurting yourself because you'll introduce painful merges at a time when changes should be minimized. The more disruptive your refactoring will be the earlier in the development cycle it should happen (and the more special process there should be for it, e.g. stop edits to the affected files as much as possible for a period of time).

Constantly merging to and from trunk is generally good practice.

Why work in a branch at all in that case? Because you have more control (you can stop merging into trunk to stabilize it for release, for example, without stopping checkins to your development branch). Because you can place a high level of validation around merging to/from trunk without impacting checkin velocity to the development branch much.

Answer (score 3):

I go with 1, make small changes when possible and check in often or else the merges become painful. Having a separate branch can make things easier if you need to work on other things at the same time or the refactoring takes more time than you originally thought. The other bonus is that it makes it easier for several people to take part in the re-factoring and you can check things in to the branch as often as you like.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest the following strategy for a scenarios where time window between releases is at least 2 months.

When you start getting close to a release, create a release branch. Release branch should be treated as *no refactoring here please* and *i am (almost) feature complete* branch. It is at this point you should start focusing your effort on stabilising the release *on the release branch*. Merge back any defect fixes from the release branch onto the trunk as necessary. Meanwhile the trunk is treated as *perpetually open for refactoring*. Also if feasible try to reduce refactoring as you get closer to a major release and accelerate it in the days immediately after one.

In case you are following a continuous release strategy (ie. a release every 1 to 2 weeks), you should not separate refactoring and coding on separate branches, unless you are doing a major surgical enhancement. In such surgical enhancement situations (which should be spaced out no less than 3 months each), drop a release from your schedule in advance whenever you intend to perform a merge, use one of the cycles for the release merge and increased testing, keep your fingers crossed and then release.

Answer (score 2):

Changes need to be either *quick* (so not too much changes under you) or else *local* (so you only care about changes in a small number of places).

Otherwise the merge can be just as much work as the refactor was. As an algorithm, optimistic locking simply doesn't work when too many transactions fail and must be restarted.

Fundamentally, you cannot allow a situation where 20 programmers in a company all change the names of 50% of the methods in the code base every day. And for that matter, if multiple people are always refactoring in the same places at the same time, then they're only undoing each other's work anyway.

If programmers are spending a lot of time manually supervising merges, then present to your managers an opportunity to increase productivity by changing the way tasks are defined and assigned.

Also, "refactor the whole system to use factories everywhere" is not a task. "Refactor this one interface and its implementations to use factories" is a task.

Answer (score 1):

This is where a good distributed VCS excels.  But I am guessing you are committed to SVN already.

Personally, I just do the refactor and then merge as soon as possible to avoid the conflict hell.  It is not the most productive method, but the least error prone.

I once had a branch that sat dormant for about 3 weeks because the feature was 'put on hold' and it was impossible to merge.  I just started the feature over again in a new branch, using the old as reference for certain parts.

Comment: SVN is the most common solution atm.  Just a guess, that was obviously wrong.

Answer (score 1):

At the risk of being obvious, I'd say try to avoid branching altogether. The amount of overhead this causes must not be underestimated. Even when you think you can't hold off any longer (release one of system in production, release two being built but also change requests to release one) still try to find another way: Is there really no way you can isolate functionality without branching (e.g. split off a "common" project and some subprojects)? Is there really no way you can integrate all code on the head (e.g. create Strategy classes that incorporate the differences or create switches to turn new features on or off)?

If you absolutely have to branch, I'd go with option 1. Try to merge as small changes as possible and do it frequently.

Comment: I'm with you, but management seem to think branches is the only way to go.

Answer (score 1):

Commit early, commit often.

Or in this case...  Merge early, merge often.

Answer (score 1):

Continuous integration is the key... 1 small batch of changes at a time...