# How to handle POST and GET requests in Elixir?

Tags: elixir, webrequest

How to handle POST and GET requests?
It is necessary to implement a web application on Elixir that handles two types of requests:

`POST / data_in`

```
{
 "data": 
        ["https://ya.ru", "https://ya.ru? 
         q=123", "yandex.ru", "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/118282"
        ]
}
```

and

`GET /data_out?from=1545221231&to=1545217638`

The POST request needs data from the request body put in storage. On a GET request, you must pass data from the repository.

Q: how does the web application communicate with the server? Need to "listen" to some port? Use Phoenix? Or Poison? Or use Plug and Cowboy? How does a web application communicate with an " external the world"? Where can I read/watch about it?

Answer (score 2):

With [HTTPoison](https://hexdocs.pm/httpoison/HTTPoison.html) (HTTP Client) and [Poison](https://github.com/devinus/poison) (JSON Encoder/Decoder) packages, this is almost as simple as your code which uses HTTParty:

```
url = "https://api.sportradar.us/nba/trial/v4/en/games/2016/11/05/schedule.json?api_key=#{api_key}"

response = HTTPoison.get!(url)
req = Poison.decode!(response.body)
```

Comment: Why mention HTTParty?